# Simple Android Client for Server giving NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, sockets, exception, networking

I am obtaining the Latitude and Longitude of the device and sending them to a server I'm running that will update the values in a database. Theres no problem gaining the positions and the server is working fine yet I am getting the error message:

```
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Code:

```
    sendGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

            String Header = "GPSUpdate";
            String Userid = "07000000001";
            String Latitude = latitudeBox.getText().toString();
            String Longitude = longitudeBox.getText().toString();

            try{
                Socket socket = new Socket("igor.gold.ac.uk", 3000);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                UserObject userObject = new UserObject();
                userObject.setHeader(Header);
                userObject.setUserid(Userid);
                userObject.setLatitude(Latitude);
                userObject.setLongitude(Longitude);

                oos.writeObject(userObject);
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                latitudeBox.setText("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I have heard of Asynctask but I'm a little unsure of what it is and am still reading up on it.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NetworkOnMainThreadException**

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).

Instead of using **Activity's main thread** use `AsyncTask` , `Thread` or `Service` for it,

Best option is put your Network operation in `AsyncTask's doINBackGround()` method.